# Matplotlib draw line on image and set axis val

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can anyone show me how to create image like that using Python?
I did draw a line but I dont know how to change x and y value.

###### Input:

[image]

###### Output:

[image]

```py
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# to read the image stored in the working directory
data = image.imread('Darwin_Maps.png')

# to draw a line from (200, 300) to (500, 100)
x = [200, 500]
y = [300, 100]
plt.plot(x, y, color="white", linewidth=3)
plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `range` to draw you lines in a loop:

```
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = image.imread('Darwin_Maps.png')
img_height, img_width, _ = data.shape

x_space = 120 #this is in pixel, you might want to change it depending on the scale of your map
x_space_km = 5
y_space = 120 #this is in pixel, you might want to change it depending on the scale of your map
y_space_km = 5

xlabel = x_space_km
for x in range(x_space, img_width, x_space):
  plt.plot([x, x], [0, img_height], color="white", linewidth=3)
  plt.text(x, 40, xlabel, color="red")
  xlabel += x_space_km

ylabel = y_space_km
for y in range(x_space, img_height, y_space):
  plt.plot([0, img_width], [y, y], color="white", linewidth=3)
  plt.text(40, y, ylabel, color="red")
  ylabel += y_space_km

plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: hi, thank you for your help. The code is working. How i give x and y a value like the result and show it. X = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, ..., 110]. Y = [0, 5, 10, 15, ..., 70]. Because i will use x and y value  to draw red dot on the map based on x, y.

Comment: sure, I edited my answer. Please accept it if it helped solve your problem

Comment: Hi, it's working perfectly. I have another question if you don't mind. I have a list of location where crocodile sightings, how i draw a red dot on the map based on location i read from the file. Example red dot number 1 x = 9 and y = 61. Thank you.

Comment: once you figured out the scale of your map (px/km) you can add the dots with `plt.scatter(x, y)`